# Turning jQuery into Angular, fixed sidebar not working (?)

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs

I am converting a jQuery Plugin into an Angular Directive, but still not working properly, or: not working at all.

[This is the behavior I want to achieve](http://plnkr.co/edit/xRXOqzaXxg6hVXDhOfV2?p=preview)

[Here is a jsfiddle also](http://jsfiddle.net/maketroli/2cseox3r/2/)

Remember that all I want to achieve with this, is the behavior on the left sidebar where says 'sticky' everywhere.

I did it with jQuery (I am new to Angular) and I need to have it working with Angular. Please go and see the [Plunkr Example](http://plnkr.co/edit/xRXOqzaXxg6hVXDhOfV2?p=preview), that behavior, is the one I want. Thanks in advance if some of you guys take the time to help me.

Look at the jQuery code:

```
$(function() {
    var offset = $("#sidebar").offset();
    var topPadding = 85;
    $(window).scroll(function() {
        if ($(window).scrollTop() > offset.top) {
            $("#sidebar").stop().animate({
                marginTop: $(window).scrollTop() - offset.top + topPadding
            });
        } else {
            $("#sidebar").stop().animate({
                marginTop: 50
            });
        };
    });
});
```

and here is my Angular Directive:

```
angular.module('capilleira.clickAndGambleWebApp.directives', [])
  .directive('sticky', function ($window) {
    return {
      restrict: 'A',
      controller: ($scope)
      link: function (scope, element, attrs) {
        var raw = element[0],
            offset = element.offset(),
            topPadding = 85;

        angular.element($window).bind('scroll', function () {
          console.log('SCROOOOOOOOOOOOOLLLL');
          if ($window.scrollTop > offset.top) {
            raw.stop().animate({
              marginTop: $window.scrollTop() - offset.top + topPadding
            });
          }
        });
      }
    }
  });
```

my directive is good at the point that once you do scroll, `the console.log` shows up.

Comment: My expectation was one of those links was going to be the working jQuery version and one was going to be your attempted (but not working) angular code. They appear to both be the same link with angular code and it's not totally clear what it's supposed to be doing. You'll probably get better/more help if it's clear what you need (and a jsfiddle/plunkr of the working jQuery code will probably go a long way with that).

Comment: @Jack I did it that way you say but I do not know why the last change I did was never saved. [look this one, I did it again](http://plnkr.co/edit/xRXOqzaXxg6hVXDhOfV2?p=preview) there is the jQuery function and below on notes in the same script.js file you will see the code for Angular Directive. please note that the behavior I want to achieve is the one on the left sidebar where says 'STICKY'everywhere.

Comment: @MarkRenton When you say: "need to have it working with Angular" you mean you need to have it working without jQuery? If jQuery is still being loaded you can use it alongside angular. So just put the same code you have in between the jQuery ready statement in your directive http://jsbin.com/puhapasaka/3/edit?js

Comment: raw is a native Javascript dom element and I believe stop() and animate() need jQuery wrapped elements to work. Furthermore, you have missed () in your if clause if ($window.scrollTop > offset.top) => if ($window.scrollTop() > offset.top)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have it working already my friends. This is the directive working properly

```
angular.module('capilleira.clickAndGambleWebApp.directives', [])
.directive('sticky', function($document) {
  return {
    restrict: 'A',
    link: function(scope, element, attrs) {
      angular.element(document).ready(function() {
        var offset = element.offset(),
            topPadding = 85;
        $document.scroll(function() {
          if ($document.scrollTop() > offset.top) {
            element.stop().animate({
              marginTop: $document.scrollTop() - offset.top + topPadding
            });
          } else {
            element.stop().animate({
              marginTop: 0
            });
          };
        });
      });
    }
  };
});
```